# Using gather() to retrieve rows from 3d tensor with 2d tensor in Pytorch

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I'm new to Pytorch and having an issue with the gather() function:

I have a 3d tensor, x[i,j,k]:

```
x=tensor([[[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]],

           [[10,11,12],
           [13,14,15],
           [16,17,18]]])
```

I have an index tensor:

```
index=tensor([[1,2,0]])
```

I want to use the values of index to iterate over x[j] and fetch the (complete) rows. I've tried gather() with all dims, squeezing, unsqueezing and it never seems to get the output I'm looking for, which would be:

```
output=tensor([[[4,5,6],
                [7,8,9],
                [1,2,3]],

               [[13,14,15],
                [16,17,18],
                [10,11,12]]])
```

I've also tried repeating the values of index to get the same shape as x but it did not work.
I know I can do this with an if loop, but I'm pretty sure I can do it with gather() as well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us set up the two tensors `x` and `index`:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(1,19).view(2,3,3)
>>> index = torch.tensor([[1,2,0]])
```

What you are looking for is the [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) operation:

```
out[i][j][k] = x[i][index[i][j][k]][k]
```

In other to apply this function, you need to expand `index` to the same shape as out. Additionally, a transpose operation is required to flip your original `index` tensor.

```
>>> i = index.T.expand_as(x)
tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [0, 0, 0]]])
```

If you compare with the pseudo code line above, you can see how every element of `i` represents the row of the original tensor `x` the operator will gather values from.

Applying the function gets us to the desired result:

```
x.gather(dim=1, index=index.T.expand_as(x))
tensor([[[ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9],
         [ 1,  2,  3]],

        [[13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18],
         [10, 11, 12]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I was missing the Transpose part. The i object seems a little conter intuitive to me: why would you need to expand the index? It feels like iteratively, you would only need each number once.

Comment: You need to expand column-wise because `torch.gather` needs this extra dimension to iterate over the columns and get the correct row number. What you need to keep in mind is that expanding a tensor does not copy the underlying data. This is just an interface manipulation to apply `torch.gather` properly because it does not unsqueeze or expand dimensions on its own...